# How do I delete the ?Say command message after sending the response in this code?

Tags: python, discord.py

I just added the `?say` command to my code and I also want the bot to delete my message I sent.

This is the say command:

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Say'])
async def say(ctx, *args):
    response = ""

    for arg in args:
        response = response + " " + arg

    await ctx.channel.send(response)
```

Comment: `await ctx.message.delete()`?

Comment: You should edit your post to be more clear about what question you're asking. It sounds like you're asking: _"How do I delete the `?Say` command message after sending the `response` in this code?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the message that you've sent to run the command, you can use [`await ctx.message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message).

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['Say'])
async def say(ctx, *args):
    response = ""

    for arg in args:
        response = response + " " + arg

    await ctx.channel.send(response)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```